# Install and purge Package leave additional Packages

Tags: package-management, kernel, aptitude

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 with Kernel 4.4.0-59-generic. `sudo aptitude install kernel-package` installs `56` packages.

```
# sudo aptitude install kernel-package
Die folgenden NEUEN Pakete werden zusätzlich installiert:
 dblatex{a} docbook-dsssl{a} docbook-utils{a} fonts-lmodern{a} fonts-texgyre{a} jadetex{a} kernel-common{a}
 kernel-package libfile-homedir-perl{a} libfile-which-perl{a} libkpathsea6{a} libosp5{a} libostyle1c2{a}
 libpotrace0{a} libptexenc1{a} libsgmls-perl{a} libsp1c2{a} libsynctex1{a} libtexlua52{a} libtexluajit2{a}
 libyaml-tiny-perl{a} libzzip-0-13{a} lmodern{a} openjade{a} preview-latex-style{a} prosper{a} ps2eps{a}
 python-apt{a} sgmlspl{a} sp{a} tex-common{a} tex-gyre{a} texlive{a} texlive-base{a} texlive-bibtex-extra{a}
 texlive-binaries{a} texlive-extra-utils{a} texlive-font-utils{a} texlive-fonts-recommended{a}
 texlive-fonts-recommended-doc{a} texlive-generic-recommended{a} texlive-latex-base{a} texlive-latex-base-doc{a}
 texlive-latex-extra{a} texlive-latex-extra-doc{a} texlive-latex-recommended{a} texlive-latex-recommended-doc{a}
 texlive-luatex{a} texlive-math-extra{a} texlive-pictures{a} texlive-pictures-doc{a} texlive-pstricks{a}
 texlive-pstricks-doc{a} tipa{a} xmlto{a} xsltproc{a}
0 Pakete aktualisiert, 56 zusätzlich installiert, 0 werden entfernt und 15 nicht aktualisiert.
0 B/811 MB an Archiven müssen heruntergeladen werden. Nach dem Entpacken werden 1.295 MB zusätzlich belegt sein.
Möchten Sie fortsetzen? [Y/n/?]
```

`sudo aptitude purge kernel-package` removes only `44` packages.

```
# sudo aptitude purge kernel-package
Die folgenden Pakete werden ENTFERNT:
 dblatex{u} docbook-dsssl{u} docbook-utils{u} fonts-texgyre{u} jadetex{u} kernel-common{u} kernel-package{p}
 libfile-homedir-perl{u} libfile-which-perl{u} libosp5{u} libostyle1c2{u} libsgmls-perl{u} libsp1c2{u}
 libyaml-tiny-perl{u} openjade{u} preview-latex-style{u} prosper{u} ps2eps{u} python-apt{u} sgmlspl{u} sp{u}
 tex-gyre{u} texlive{u} texlive-bibtex-extra{u} texlive-extra-utils{u} texlive-font-utils{u}
 texlive-fonts-recommended{u} texlive-fonts-recommended-doc{u} texlive-generic-recommended{u}
 texlive-latex-base{u} texlive-latex-base-doc{u} texlive-latex-extra{u} texlive-latex-extra-doc{u}
 texlive-latex-recommended{u} texlive-latex-recommended-doc{u} texlive-luatex{u} texlive-math-extra{u}
 texlive-pictures{u} texlive-pictures-doc{u} texlive-pstricks{u} texlive-pstricks-doc{u} tipa{u} xmlto{u}
 xsltproc{u}
0 Pakete aktualisiert, 0 zusätzlich installiert, 44 werden entfernt und 15 nicht aktualisiert.
0 B an Archiven müssen heruntergeladen werden. Nach dem Entpacken werden 1.156 MB frei werden.
Möchten Sie fortsetzen? [Y/n/?]
```

I have to remove the packages my hand:

```
sudo aptitude purge libkpathsea6 fonts-lmodern libpotrace0 libptexenc1 libsynctex1 libtexlua52 libtexluajit2 libzzip-0-13 lmodern tex-common texlive-base texlive-binaries
```

What is the reason for such a behaviour? Is this a bug?

=======================================================================

I have opened a bug ticket in Ubuntu [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kernel-package/+bug/1658312): `1658312`. Please hit the button if it affects also you.